# Autolayout woes. NSToolBarItem->NSView->NSTabView->NSTabItem->NSButtons need to resize when language changes

Tags: xcode, cocoa, autolayout

I've spent about 5 hours on this already so I'm pretty desperate for any hints or suggestions because I've exhausted modifying every constraint I can think of.

*Note I am adding constraints strictly through Interface Builder.  I don't think I need to add anything programmatically, but I am open to it.*

This is my current object hierarchy:
`NSToolBarItem->NSView->NSTabView->NSTabItem->NSButtons`

My constraints, respectively:
`NSTabView` is constrainted w/ 0 constant to the all 4 sides of the container `NSView`

`NSTabItem` does not have a size, it just takes on the size of the `NSTabView`.  Therefore, no constraints are applied

I have 2-3 `NSButtons` that are 10-pixel separated, and the end buttons are constrained to the `NSTabView`  However, the button on the very right does **not** have a trailing constraint to the superview

My problem is that the buttons are "hugging" too much, and won't take on the width of their intrinsic size.

Here are screenshots of the preview in interface builder for a `NSTabItem`

[image]

Here is the german preview:

[image]

Looks good right?

Well at runtime, this is what I see:

[image]

[image]

To me this is clearly an issue with hugging/compression resistance priorities.
I have `1` set as the hugging priority to every view in my hierarchy, and `1000` set as the compression resistance, as well as little variations in the numbers.  But I can't get the buttons to avoid compression/over-hugging.  I have been able to get **one** button to avoid over-hugging, but the other button will always suffer as a result

I am aware of the gap at the very right of my `NSTabView`.  This is because I put a width on the container `NSView`, just to get something showing.

I have gotten to a state where it looks good in English, but as soon as I switch to German the buttons get squooshed.

I know I'm missing a lot of details but I don't know what's important to know or not.  Please comment if you need any more details; at this point I will take any suggestions gladly

Comment: What is the view hierarchy?

Comment: Cocoa sorry, and the view hierarchy is at the top of the question :)

Comment: A tabview in the toolbar?

Comment: How do you create the red buttons? The size of the buttons is the same as the preview, the text is bigger.

Comment: Ah that's it.  Subclassed `NSButton`, and not overriding `intrinsicSize` to account for the special font.  Thanks!